# Enabling Azure AD auth on one page of a web forms application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am the dev lead on a web forms project. There are 2 "modes" to the login page, one for customers, and one for admins.

For additional security, we would like to enforce admin users to authenticate with their Azure AD creds.

Is there a way at the application level for a specific page/URL to kick off the Azure AD auth based on a specific URL? We cannot do this from Azure itself as obviously our customers are not in our AD account.

Comment: look at multi tenant app registration, it may suit you needs

Answer (score 0):

Just mark admin view controllers with [Authorize] attribute and configure Openid authentication from within the app. This means all views served from this controlled class will require user authentication.

There are a lot of examples on the web how to do this. In case of .net core 2.0 here is the sample.

**AccountController.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignIn()
        {
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            return Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignOut()
        {
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
            return SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignedOut()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AccessDenied()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And in **Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

and in **Configure** Method add

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

And lastly in **appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "TenantId": "[Enter the Tenant Id (Obtained from the Azure portal. Select 'Endpoints' from the 'App registrations' blade and use the GUID in any of the URLs), e.g. da41245a5-11b3-996c-00a8-4d99re19f292]",
    "ClientId": "[Enter the Client Id (Application ID obtained from the Azure portal), e.g. ba74781c2-53c2-442a-97c2-3d60re42f403]",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  } 
}
```

More here

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

Comment: Thanks, but this is web forms project, your solution seems to be for net core web app

Comment: It's the same in webforms (same principle) just different code to initialize it.

Example http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/24/protecting-an-asp-net-webforms-app-with-openid-connect-and-azure-ad/